# invalid lvalue in assignment

Tags: c, integer, lvalue

This code is a swapping of integers in an array.  The total size of the array is 100.  When I compile, I get an error stating "invalid lvalue in assignment".  What am I doing wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    int a[110],I,n,temp;

    printf("\n enter the values");
    for(I=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[I]);
    }
    for(I=0&&n=99;I<51&&n>50;I++&&n--) #here is the error
    {
        temp=a[I];
        a[I]=a[n];
        a[n]=temp;
        printf("\n the values are %d and %d ", a[I],a[n]);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: 1. `void main()` is not a valid `main()` signature- 2. Your code uses combinations of `i` and `I`- 3. # is not for comments in [tag:c], was this code another language that you translated?

Comment: 4. Spaces are there for a reason. Formatting & indenting your code properly will greatly enhance readability. 5. Provide a [mcve] and learn [ask]

Answer (score 4):

Two issues:

```
for(I=0;i<100;i++)
```

The variable `i` is not declared.  You probably want `I` instead:

```
for(I=0;I<100;I++)
```

Next is here:

```
for(I=0&&n=99;I<51&&n>50;I++&&n--)
```

The first part of the `for` is an assignment.  You don't want to use `&&` here.  Similarly with the third part.

The reason you're getting the "invalid lvalue in assignment" error has to do with the order of operations.  `&&` has higher precedence than `=`.  So the first part of the `for` looks like this with implicit parenthesis:

```
I=(0&&n)=99
```

The expression `0&&n` is not a valid lvalue but it is on the left side of an assignment, so that's why you get the error.

In the third part of the `for`, `I` is 0 on the first iteration, so the first time `I++` runs `I` becomes 1 but the expression evaluates to 0, so the `&&` operator prevents `n--` from running.

In both the first and third parts of the `for`, use the comma operator instead, and add parenthesis in the second part for clarity:

```
for(I=0,n=99;(I<51)&&(n>50);I++,n--)
```

Also, `main` should always return `int`, not `void`.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up `I` with `i`. C is a case sensitive language.

Also: change the `for` conditions (use `,` instead of `&&`), like this:

```
for(i=0, n=99; i<51 && n>50; i++, n--)
```

`main()` should return int insead of `void`.

Resulting code should be:

```
int main()
{
    int a[110],i,n,temp;
    printf("\n enter the values:\n");
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0, n=99; i<51 && n>50; i++, n--)
    {
        temp=a[i];
        a[i]=a[n];
        a[n]=temp;
        printf("\n the values are %d and %d ", a[i],a[n]);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change to what?  You may want to complete this answer.

Comment: To the OP: don't use *conio.h* it's not a standard header, and `getch()` which is declared in *conio.h* isn't standard as well.

Comment: @Clifford - Answer wasn't complete indeed. Updated now.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use lowercase `I` here

```
 for(inti=0;i<100;i++)
{
   scanf("%d",&a[I]);
}
```

you should place comma `,` in following for loop, instead of `&&`

```
for(int i = 0,n = 99; i < 51 && n > 50; i++ , n--)
```

Comment: The one that is actually declared is the `I`.

Comment: @iharob it is declared, but it is never incremented, user will put 100 input, but only first element of an array will be initialized.